# Optimize "tagging" regex

Tags: php, regex

I currently use this piece of code to reduce a given text to a valid "tagging" format (only lowercase, a-z and minus allowed) by removing/replacing invalid characters

```
        $zip_filename = strtolower($original);
        $zip_filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\-]/g", '-', $zip_filename); //replace invalid chars
        $zip_filename = preg_replace("/-+/g", '-', $zip_filename); // reduce consecutive minus to only one
        $zip_filename = preg_replace("/^-/g", '', $zip_filename); // removing leading minus
        $zip_filename = preg_replace("/-$/g", '', $zip_filename); // remove trailing minus
```

Any hints on how to put at least the regex into a single one?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why wouldn't $zip_filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\-]/g", '', $zip_filename); //replace invalid chars with nothing
work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$zip_filename = trim(preg_replace("/[^a-z]+/", '-', $zip_filename),'-');
```

Explanation:

1. `A-Z` is useless since it should be lower case
2. Adding `+` after right bracket will replace one or more consecutive invalid chars
3. Using `trim` with second parameter - character to trim form beginning and end will speed up the code
4. Removing `\-` from `preg_replace` will also take car of hyphens between invalid chars / multiple consecutive hyphens, replacing them to single one.

Comment: That doesn't take care of multiple consecutive hyphens, I don't think.

Comment: @Platinum - You're right.  It also doesn't take care of consecutive spaces, or leading or trailing dashes.

Comment: Platinum is right. 
0ßDie--s §$"%& idsfg sdg$
will result in
die--s-idsfg-sdg
(one hyphen too much)

Comment: Ah, I like this better than mine now, especially since I'm not a php guy and didn't know about the optional parameter for the trim function.  I do think you need to perform one more trim for spaces.  The original code effectively eliminated leading and trailing spaces as well... I think that's the only thing yours doesn't do now.

Comment: Nevermind, you can disregard that.  You're replacing spaces with dashes, and then trimming the dashes.  It's a little bit redundant processing but not bad at all, and very easy to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This should simplify it considerably...

```
$zip_filename = trim(strtolower($original));
$zip_filename = preg_replace("/\s\s+|--+|[^a-zA-Z-]/g", '-', $zip_filename);
```

The `trim` will take care of the spaces before and after the string.  Also note the `\s\s+` and `--+`.  These are more efficient at finding duplicates.  They'll *only* match those characters if there are 2 or more in succession, therefore avoiding unnecessary replacement operations.

But technically it'd still be possible to have leading or trailing dashes.  And for that you'd still need this...

```
$zip_filename = preg_replace("/^-|-$/g", '', $zip_filename);
```

(This last operation couldn't really be combined with the other since you're using a different replacement string.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll only make the code more difficult to understand/maintain by combining these four operations into one.

You also don't need the complexity and performance hit of regular expression-based operations to achieve what you need.

The reduction of double to single minus signs may be more readily achieved with a looped call to str_replace:

```
while (substr_count($zip_filename, '--')) {
    $zip_filename = str_replace('--', '-', $zip_filename);
}
```

Wrapping this up in a well-named class method will abstract away any apparent complexity and aid the readability of the code.

The last two operations can be handled by the [trim()](http://php.net/trim) function:

```
$zip_filename = trim($zip_filename, '-');
```

You can then replace your regular expression-based operations with something less cpu aggressive and arguably easier for others to understand:

```
//replace invalid chars
$zip_filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\-]/g", '-', strtolower($original)); 

// reduce consecutive minus to only one
while (substr_count($zip_filename, '--')) {
    $zip_filename = str_replace('--', '-', $zip_filename);
}

// remove leading and trailing minus
$zip_filename = trim($zip_filename, '-');
```